# Interceptor for EJB 2.x

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, interceptor, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I want to log every incoming EJB call into DB.EJB 3 provides @AroundInvoke to intercept the incoming call and outgoing. 
Do we have similar thing for EJB 2.x?

Need suggestion how can i achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "EJB 2.x".

If you mean an EJB module without an ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor or with ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor declared that declares version="3.0" (or higher) but using EJB 2.x-style component interfaces, then yes, interceptors can be applied to any EJB regardless of the interface type they use.

If you mean an EJB module with ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor that declares version="2.1" (or lower), then no, there is no way to specify an interceptor in such a module.  However, if you are running a modern application server with support for at least EJB 3.0, you should be able to just adjust the ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor to be version 3.0 (or higher).  The EJBs should continue to run as-is, but you should then be able to declare interceptors.

Comment: Thanks Brett yes i have ejb-jar.xml and 2.0 is mention on that So you are saying there is no way to implement interpreter in 2.0?
If i change version from 2.0 to 3.0 will i able to implement interceptor without adding any jar?
Thanks